# How to clone a MacBook Pro disk into bootable external device

Tags: macbook-pro, backup, mojave, startup, external-disk

I would like to clone my MacBook Pro (15-inch 2018, macOS Mojave 10.14.6), which I will call "Mac", into an external USB hard drive, which I will call "backup".

I want to do this in such a way that I can completely wipe the SSD on the Mac, reinstall it from scratch (i.e. with Big Sur), and I can even gift this laptop to someone else and buy a new one, and at any moment I can plug the backup to a similar laptop (so no Apple Silicon) and boot from it.

**What would the correct procedure be to achieve this goal?**

Time Machine is not appropriate for this purpose, since it must first be restored, and I want to run the macOS Mojave on the backup, not whichever one is installed in the internal SSD.

I am not sure whether `dd if=/dev/disk0 of=/dev/disk[USB]` is sufficient:

- Will FileVault cause me grief?
- Is any (encryption?) information stored in the Secure Enclave which may
  not be available on a different, albeit similar laptop? The Keychain (e.g. the Wi-Fi passwords), maybe?
- Is the entire macOS Operating System and settings stored on `/dev/disk0` or is there any information stored on a different storage medium on the Mac? (e.g. NVRAM)

My *actual* use case is to completely reinstall the Mac from scratch and copy data to the new installation only as needed, using the previous Time Machine, but I may need at any time to run the old image in case it becomes necessary on a moment's notice. Switching laptops is a real possibility - I might get a 2019 version or an iMac to replace this one, and I'd like to ensure the backup can still be booted from, and will contain all information currently available on the Mac.

Comment: I can't answer for `dd`, but Super Duper or Carbon Copy Cloner both can do this. Super Duper doesn't work with Big Sur yet, but sounds like that's a non-issue. It will make a disk that's bootable directly off the external disk, including from other similar hardware.

Comment: Both seem to be paid solutions, but both appear to provide a free trial that should be enough for a one-shot operation. I prefer a free alternative like `dd` if possible, but if it isn't, I will consider using Super Duper, since the trial only seems to restrict scheduling features.

Comment: If you are running encrypted and on a T2 Mac I do not believe you can make a `dd` image and then boot that image on another Mac.

Comment: Can confirm on https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208862 and System Information that my MacBook Pro contains the T2 Security Chip. The contents of /dev/disk0 are the actual bits on-disk (ciphertext) or are they the plaintext as decrypted by T2? If I connect an external hard drive, will the T2 chip interfere with it?

Comment: Don't mess about with dd.  The developers of Carbon Copy Cloner and SuperDuper have put lots of time and effort in making products which correctly make bootable clones.

Comment: Your scenario of a new Mac will not work. You will not be able to boot a new Mac with a macOS 10.14 boot disk.  A new Mac will come with Big Sur and, depending on its first release date, will probably be able to run Catalina. You need a new Mac first released before October 2019 to boot a 10.14.6 disk.

Comment: @Gilby I understand that my current architecture is not compatible with the new Apple Silicon, but I would expect it to be compatible with 2019's MacBook Pros and iMacs. The reason you say it will not work is related to Apple Silicon or something else?

Comment: All versions of macOS 'know' about a fixed range of hardware.  Too old and it won't work (not your problem). Too new (more recently released than the specific macOS version) and it won't work. Taking macOS 10.14.6 - it was released July 2019 - it did not and still doesn't know about 'future' hardware - 'future' hardware being anything released after July 2019. So macOS 10.14.6 knows nothing about a MacBook Pro (2019, 16inch) which was released in November 2019 - that MBP requires macOS 10.15.1 or later.  Nothing to do with Apple Silicon.

Comment: With the specific models you mention.  Yes, a MacBook Pro 2019 model released before July 2019 or a iMac 2019 (released April 2019) are compatible with your 10.14.6 boot drive (when you create it).  But later MBPs and the 2020 iMac will not work with your boot drive.

Comment: @Gilby I appreciate you taking the time to check the specific models. I'm not expecting to keep this backup forever; only as long as I need to be comfortable with the newer system while having instant access to the previous version in case I need it. This looks possible within the realms of devices released between 2018 and 2019 (and probably earlier).